# Pass the youtube video ID to another JS file

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

i had already check whether a url is a valid youtube video URL and get the youtube video ID from it, so far I am using a simple javascript split function in order to achieve this, however now i want to pass this ID to another javascript file, where there is youtube palyer and i want to play that video on that page.

I have been viewing other stackoverflow threads

I need something that passes the videoID's to another file where it will be executed:

http(s)://www.youtu.be/videoID

http(s)://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoID
(and optionally any other short URL's which the script automatically detects whether it contains a youtube video)

Any ideas which can be handled by the browser quick/efficient is greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using just html and javascript or any libraries or other languages. Where is the second file in relation to the first, do you need a second file?

Comment: i am just using html and javascript, and for iframe, i am using youtube iframe api.